# $stateParams are empty in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui.router to load a view then different APIs route that need 2 params : username and id

app.route.js

```
 angular
    .module('app.route',['ui.router'])
    .config([
        '$stateProvider',
        '$urlRouterProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

            $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/{username}/{id:int}');
            $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/{username}/{id:int}');
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/{username}/{id:int}');

            $stateProvider.state('module', {
                url: '/{username}/{id:int}',
                templateUrl: 'app/module/module.html',
                controller: 'ModuleController',
            });

        }
    ]);
```

module.controller.js

```
 function ModuleController($state, $stateParams) {

    console.log('$stateParams: ', $stateParams); // returns empty
    console.log('$state.params: ', $state.params); // returns empty
  }
```

even if my url seems fine (eg. http://myurl.com/#/johndoe/2 ) both params are ignored. Do I miss something ?

Here's the output :

```
 $stateParams:  Object {}
 $state.params:  Object {}
```

I don't have any errors related to it. 
I get some 404 about routes because of course, params are expected.

Comment: I use a classical <div ui-view='module'></div> on index page

Comment: Can you setup a plunkr?

Comment: are you sure of the declaration of your controller, could we see full code ? `angular.controller('ModuleController', function($state, $stateParams){...})`

Comment: Just created a plunker and could reproduce same issue : http://plnkr.co/edit/pEvfe0W5oiimwWzhoxMe?p=preview

Comment: You are not injecting `$state` and `$stateParams` in your controller declaration. `.controller('ModuleController', ["$state", "$stateParams", ModuleController]);`

Comment: Not sure you can specifiy a state in the `ui-view` attribute. You don't pass any param. http://plnkr.co/edit/hyb17Qsfc8qwDuMqDDNZ

Comment: @Jasen, yes in fact in my code I did an injector I didn't put in Plunker `ModuleController.$inject = ['$state', '$stateParams']; ` @MarnaWalter the thing is I need to do it only when loading the page :/

Comment: I couldn't find how to pass params unless by passing params via ui-sref as @MamaWalter mentioned it. This is not ideal, but I'll find a work around. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with what you have above.

1. You had ng-controller="ModuleController" in your html a couple times - those instances were getting created but I think you only wanted the one controller associated with the ui-view to be created. When you define a controller for a state you don't need to use ng-controller.
2. The `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` needs to go to a fully defined state - the state params need to be defined. Typically this would be a "home" state without params, but I updated your example to go to /user/none/0. Your version had the `otherwise` going to a invalid state since "{id:int}" isn't an int.

You can remove the `$urlRouterProvider.when` statements and update the `otherwise` to `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/user/none/0');` to go to a default state. Then get to different routes with ui-sref or $state.go:

`<a ui-sref="module({username:'user 1', id: 1})">User 1</a>`

3. In the html you were using a named view (`ui-view="module"`) but not in the state definition...just change the html to `ui-view`.

Here's an updated plunker based on your previous one: http://plnkr.co/edit/LaSioepCFrt8kmNbUm57?p=preview